# How to establish a permanent connection between an EC2 and an RDS for data transfer?

Tags: python, django

I am still learning AWS so this is kind of a basic question, but I've been researching and trying things without any success.

I launched an Postgresql RDS on AWS as well as a EC2 Ubuntu server running apache. I wrote some Python code using Django and Django-rest-framework to query the database and return some data to a mobile app. Both the EC2 and RDS are on the same VPC. I was wondering how does one go around establishing a permanent connection between the EC2 and the RDS so that when I query from a web app or a mobile app I get some data back.

This is the code I have so far in my views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import HttpResponse
from rest_framework.renderers import JSONRenderer
from rest_framework.parsers import JSONParser
from .models import UserDatabase
from .serializers import UserDatabaseSerializer


class JSONResponse(HttpResponse):
    """
    An HttpResponse that renders its content into JSON.
    """

    def __init__(self, data, **kwargs):
        content = JSONRenderer().render(data)
        kwargs['content_type'] = 'application/json'
        super(JSONResponse, self).__init__(content, **kwargs)


def database_list(request):
    if request.method == 'GET':
        database = UserDatabase.objects.all()
        serializer = UserDatabaseSerializer(database, many=True)
        return JSONResponse(serializer.data)
```

In my models.py:

```
from django.db import models



class UserDatabase(models.Model):
    """
    """
    id = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True)
    email = models.CharField(max_length=320)
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    passw = models.CharField(max_length=60)
```

And in serializers.py

```
from .models import UserDatabase
from rest_framework import serializers


class UserDatabaseSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    """
    """
    class Meta:
        model = UserDatabase
        fields = ("id","email","first_name","last_name","passw")
```

**EDIT:** To be more precise what I'm asking is which networking library can establish a permanent connection between the EC2 and RDS without having to manually reestablished it every time. I've looked into python's build in **socket** but that wont do.

Comment: Can you go into a more detailed explanation of what you mean by "I was wondering how does one go around establishing a permanent connection between the EC2 and the RDS so that when I query from a web app or a mobile app I get some data back."? That sentence doesn't make sense to me.

Comment: @MarkB I'm having a hard time explaining this for which I am sorry. What I meant to say is how does the networking between a django app and a Postgresql RDS work. If for example I want to GET some data from a mobile app I query the REST API which will query the database and return the data to the mobile app. What i'm struggling with is making the REST API "communicate" with the RDS.

Comment: You would just use the same type of database connection that you would use to connect to any other database from Python. There is nothing special about EC2 or RDS that would require you to do anything differently from how you would normally use a database.

Comment: @MarkB Can you please explain in  some more detail please I'm a beginner.  I have never connected to a database before.

Comment: I'm not a Python programmer, sorry. You need to stop searching for EC2 and RDS and AWS stuff and just search for how to use a database in Python.